# Elements within an un-ordered list do not take up 100% width of their parent container

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having a strange issue where children of an un-ordered list are not stretching to take up 100% of their parent's width when their parent has a fixed with and `overflow: scroll`.

When you hover over a hyperlink within the list, the hover effect does not apply to the entirety of the text.

I can't let the text break onto the next line.

Been banging my head against the wall on this for a while. Any ideas?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
    .container{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
      width: 250px;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      overflow: scroll;

      ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    }

    a{
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      clear:both;
      padding: 15px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;

      &:hover{
        background: white;
        color: black;
      }
    }
```

[And a link to a codepen demonstrating the issue](https://codepen.io/richardsonweb/pen/xeRxMW)

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to reproduce the situation on Stack Overflow, rather than making people go to another site. You will have to change your "CSS" from LESS/SASS to actual CSS, however.

Answer (score 0):

Adding width 100% in ul should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the styles on `.container a`. Change `display` to `block` and remove the whitespace nowrap rule.

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
      width: 250px;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      overflow: scroll;
}

.container ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
}

.container a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      clear:both;
      padding: 15px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
}
.container a:hover {
        background: white;
        color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 100%` from the `a` element. Everything else is fine. A `100%` width implies `250px` in your case.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clear: both;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 100%; */
}

a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following two rules: `white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;` from the `a`. The white-space will block the text to break down into a new line, the width will make the `a` tag as long as the container is which is `250px - scrollbar if there is`.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear:both;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
a:hover{
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px;">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px;">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a>
          
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 50px;">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 50px;">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 50px;">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
      </ul>
          
        </li>
      <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px;">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link with a long name that stretches the container</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I also changed the `overflow` to `overflow-y` because there's no meaning to show the scroll on the x axis, if anyway it's not possible to scroll in that way.